# ASP.NET Core - How to customize some fields in IdentityDbContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In ASP.NET Core IdentityDbContext, I am using EF Code First. I have:

```
public class DDMDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, long, IdentityUserClaim<long>, ApplicationUserRole, IdentityUserLogin<long>, IdentityRoleClaim<long>, IdentityUserToken<long>>
{
    public DDMDbContext(DbContextOptions<DDMDbContext> options)
    : base(options) { }

    public virtual DbSet<ApplicationRole> ApplicationRole { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<ApplicationUserRole> ApplicationUserRole { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUserRole>(userRole =>
        {
            userRole.HasKey(ur => new { ur.UserId, ur.RoleId });

            userRole.HasOne(ur => ur.Role)
                .WithMany(r => r.UserRoles)
                .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.RoleId)
                .IsRequired();

            userRole.HasOne(ur => ur.User)
                .WithMany(r => r.UserRoles)
                .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.UserId)
                .IsRequired();
        });

    }
}

namespace DDM.API.Core.Data.Identity
{
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public ICollection<ApplicationUserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
    }

    public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole
    {
        public ICollection<ApplicationUserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
    }

    public class ApplicationUserRole : IdentityUserRole<long>
    {
        public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
        public virtual ApplicationRole Role { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I found that in ApplicationUser, these fields are required.:

```
EmailConfirmed
PhoneNumberConfirmed
TwoFactorEnabled
LockoutEnabled
AccessFailedCount
```

I tried to use:

```
            entity.Property(m => m.EmailConfirmed).IsRequired(false);
            entity.Property(m => m.PhoneNumberConfirmed).IsRequired(false);
            entity.Property(m => m.TwoFactorEnabled).IsRequired(false);
            entity.Property(m => m.LockoutEnabled).IsRequired(false);
            entity.Property(m => m.AccessFailedCount).IsRequired(false);
```

But got error:

> The property 'ApplicationUser.EmailConfirmed' cannot be marked as nullable/optional because the type of the property is 'bool' which is not a nullable type. Any property can be marked as non-nullable/required, but only properties of nullable types can be marked as nullable/optional.

How do I change these fields to **Not Required**?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should leave those properties as they are, just ignore them for sign in, lockout, etc. Check this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-configuration?view=aspnetcore-6.0
So, for Sign-In you could use:

```
services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
{
    // Default SignIn settings.
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = false;
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedPhoneNumber = false;
});
```

And rest of properties could be ignored by similar logic.

Answer (score 0):

```
EmailConfirmed
PhoneNumberConfirmed
TwoFactorEnabled
LockoutEnabled
AccessFailedCount
```

These properties was hardcoded at the root level of `IdentityRole<>` in .Net Identity, with type `bool`, not `bool?` so it cannot be optional even if we configure through fluent API.

> How do I change these fields to Not Required?

I don't get it so far... If we doesn't need it, why not simply ignore it ? Like we usually do with `userRole.Ignore(x => x.EmailConfirmed);`. But override it to become optional doesn't make so much sense.

Just a caveat, `UserManager`, `LoginManager` and a few more manager which ever make use of those property would get their default value (for example, `bool` property ignored always have `false` value), then that might cause some unexpected behavior afterward.